# App rejected for lack of IPv6, is this a server or app issue?

Tags: ios, networking, ipv6

Apple rejected an app because it didnt work on their IPv6 network. I've managed to test this on my end using an ipv6 only address and can see that the third party API i'm using is unreachable when using an IPv6-only address.

Any time i try to use the API I get the response

`A server with the specified hostname could not be found`

The same thing happens if I manually go the URL in safari, whereas other IPv6-ready sites like gmail etc work.

**So my question is** do I need to get the developers of the API I'm querying to update their servers to support IPv6 in order to get this working, or is there something I should be doing on the app side in order to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to change any external servers. It's all about the client. If by this "third party API" you mean they have a library which you include into your app, then perhaps they are doing something in their code that is not working correctly; if this is the case, then you need to ask them to fix their client library.

Comment: Yes I'm using a third party SDK which handles all the connections to the API, so it sounds like I should be looking into the provided client? But even if I try going to the endpoint in my browser it gives me a "requested url could not be reached" error. Surely if even the browser can't go to the endpoint URL, the iOS client can't ether? for example, the oAuth page won't even load in the web view when i'm connected to IPv6.

Comment: @Koonga To be sure, you need to set up a test NAT64/DNS64 network on your Mac [following Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16) and test your app on a device using that network.

Comment: thanks mate, I did try that with those instructions and the app seems to work fine, unless I manually turn off IPv4 in the network settings so that it only accepts ipv6 (Network > Advanced > TCP/IP > Configure IPV4 to OFF). However the instructions don't mention to do this so I assume it's not necessary. also when I do that, almost no website works, including stack overflow! When running on a NAT64/DNS64 network as outlined in that doc the app works fine, so i guess this indicates the problem apple is experiencing may not have anything to do with ipv6 at all?